# Show that $Cov(X, Y) = p(1-p)\left(E[Y|X=1]-E[Y|X=0]\right)$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ is a Bernouilli distributed random variable, i.e. $X = 1$ with probability $p \in [0, 1]$; and $X = 0$ otherwise. Let $Y$ denote another random variable. I am trying to show that
\begin{equation}
Cov(X, Y) = p(1-p)\left(E[Y|X=1]-E[Y|X=0]\right)
\end{equation}
but can't do it! Here is my attempt:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Cov(X, Y) & = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] \\
&  = pE[Y|X=1]-p(1-p)(pE[Y|X=1]+(1-p)E[Y|X = 0]) \\
& = E[Y|X=1](p - p^2(1-p))+ E[Y|X=0]p(1-p)^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
but I can't tidy this up into the requisite form. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** As helpfully pointed out by @drhab, I had for some reason inserted $E[X] = p(1-p)$ instead of $E[X] = p$; and this explains why I couldn't obtain the desired expression.

Comment: It seems that you substitute $EX=p(1-p)$. However $EX=p$.

Comment: Oh no! I knew I had done something stupid here...

Comment: I guess best to delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=p$$

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=p\mathbb{E}[Y|X=1]+(1-p)\mathbb{E}[Y|X=0]$$

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=p\mathbb{E}[Y|X=1]$$

substitute in

$$cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

and get the requested proof